# Create mailbox in Exchange 2003 using C# running on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I'm getting desperate so was hoping someone could help. We've re-written an old VB app that uses CDOEXM to create mailboxes in Exchange 2003. The new C# code is very similar and looks like this:

```
        CDOEXM.IMailboxStore mailbox;
        mailbox = (IMailboxStore)user.NativeObject;
        mailbox.CreateMailbox(homeMDB);
        user.CommitChanges();
```

The server running the code needed to have Exchange Management Tools installed for it to work (that installs the CDOEXM libraries that we require)

This works fine on XP, but we're also moving to Windows 2008 64bit servers, and I have been unable to install Exchange Management Tools on here because it says there's a compatibility issue.

Can anyone recommend a way around this? As I said, we're getting desperate because this is going to prevent a production release if we can't solve it, so would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

EDIT: incidentally I manually registered the CDOEXM dlls as a bit of a bodge, and I now get this error:

Problem creating mailboxSystem.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at CDOEXM.IMailboxStore.CreateMailbox(String HomeMDBURL)

The homeMDBURL I am using is a valid one as far as I can tell though

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CDOEXM is supported on Windows 2008. What about having a Windows 2003 Server around which hosts a WebService that does the mailbox creation stuff?

Another option is to create the mailbox without using CDOEXM. Note that this approach is totally unsupported by Microsoft. But if you populate enough properties (I don't know them all out of my head) like homeMDB and others, the Recipient Update Service (RUS) will create the mailbox on its next run. If I recall it correctly, the RUS runs every two minutes by default.

Btw, you did run your C# program as a 32bit process, right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've been so focussed on trying to get it to work on our new architecture I didn't consider setting up an older server just for this purpose. I guess that might be what we have to do actually, especially if the alternatives are not officially supported. Interested in what you say about 32 bit process too. I haven't tried, but the code is compiled on XP so I'm guessing it's 32 bit already (?). Would that make a difference for this? Sorry, not that familiar with COM stuff so not sure of the implications. Thanks

Comment: .NET code can be compiled for x86, x64 or Any Cpu. When compiled as Any Cpu it would run as x64 process on an 64bit Windows and as 32bit on an 32bit Windows.

Comment: Ended up following these steps: http://internationalmanofawesome.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/installing-exchange-system-manager-2003-on-windows-2008-r2/, and also there was something wrong with the domain the server was connected to but when we created a new domain it all worked fine, so CDOEXM can be made to work with 2008 with a bit of bodging...